# Pass parameter to Django REST framework serializer to use with model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a class `Object` with a method `state` that takes a datetime parameter `dt`. How do I pass the datetime parameter from the URL to `Object.state()`?

The model:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    def state(self, dt=datetime.datetime.now()) -> dict:
        ...stuff...
        return {'dt': dt, 'other_stuff': stuff}
```

The view:

```
class ObjectDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = models.Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ObjectSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'dt': self.request.query_params.get('dt', datetime.datetime.now())}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And the serializer classes:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    state = StateSerializer(read_only=True, context={'dt': self.context['dt']})

    class Meta:
        model = models.Object
        fields = ('state')

class StateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    dt = serializers.DateTimeField()
    ... other stuff...
```

As you can see I am trying to pass `dt` as extra context in the line `state = StateSerializer(read_only=True, context={'dt': dt})` having set the context earlier in the view. The problem here is that when `ObjectSerializer` is initialized `dt` is not accessible via `self.context['dt']` as `self` is not defined.

Comment: What is the purpose of `state` ? Should it be updated every time the object is saved or it has another idea?

Comment: @wencakisa `state` is dependent on the `dt` passed. It is generated from the object state and other things and is a dict. It is not writable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to make `state` a `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and then define a `get_state` method. The new `ObjectSeializer` looks like this:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    state = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Object
        fields = ('state')

    def get_state(self, obj):
        state = obj.state(self.context['dt'])
        state_serializer = StateSerializer(state)
        return state_serializer.data
```